# SMPS Transformer Notation Confusion

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

While designing an LM2586 SMPS circuit using the TI Workbench, the software recommended the following transformer:

[image: SMPS Transformer]

This is apparently the [749196510](http://katalog.we-online.com/pbs/datasheet/749196510.pdf).

The TI workbench states that this is a 89.1uH part. However, the datasheet states that the inductance base is 9.9uH. Even if I were to connect all 3 primary windings in series, surely that would only result in 29.7uH? Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Looks like a f$%^ up on the part of TI

Comment: @Andyaka But they've done it on more than one part. I tried changing the parameters of the power supply and it chose a different inductor. Same problem: it said it was a 47.7uH part, but the datasheet said the base inductance is 5.3uH.

Comment: I think you should let the software decide on values but you do the part selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inductance goes as turns squared, so all three primary windings in series would get you 89.1uH.